# Why is my FormData object always empty?

Tags: typescript, form-data

I'm trying to add some data to formData like this:

```
params = {'code': 'h1'}
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('parameters', JSON.stringify(params));
```

When I try to get the data from the formData like this: `formData['parameters']` it returns `undefined`
and `formData.entries.length` is `0`.
I looked at some sites and saw that this is the way to do that.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you getting undefined? where's params defined? how are you calling the data? are you trying via console.log?

Comment: you are using `const formData`, so you wouldn't be able to append anything to it, try changing it to `let formData`. Not sure what that syntax is unless it's something I've not came across in JS, I'd write it as `let formData = new FormData();`

Comment: @martincarlin87 That's not right. `const` only means that you cannot assign anything new to the variable. You do however can change its properties and call its methods to do so.

Comment: i tried to change it from const to let, but still the result are same

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, Typescript, I removed the : FormData, nothing changed

Comment: @N.Bar: Ok, you can keep the `: FormData` then. It is not necessary however.

Answer (score 9):

Your `FormData` object is actually not empty. The way you are trying to access the data after appending it, is wrong.

For me the following works:

```js
const params = {'code': 'h1'}
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('parameters', JSON.stringify(params));

for (const entry of formData.entries())
{
    document.write(entry);
}
```

Side notes:

- As `formData.entries()` returns an [interator object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries), there is no `length` property.
- There is also no indexer `[]` defined. So you need to retrieve values using the [get() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) as shown by Daniel Beck in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You're declaring the formData object incorrectly</strike> (edit: for javascript. The question wasn't originally tagged with typescript, which I'm not familiar enough with)

```js
const params={'code': 'h1'}
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('parameters', JSON.stringify(params))
// confirm:
console.log(formData.get('parameters'))
```

...but in case you're trying to set multiple parameters on formData, instead of just one named "parameters", you might want to be doing this instead:

```js
const params={
  'code': 'h1',
  'foo': 'bar'
}

const formData = new FormData()
Object.keys(params).forEach((k) => {
  formData.append(k, params[k])
})

// confirm:
console.log(formData.get('code'))
console.log(formData.get('foo'))
```